# How to get info about which XSL version XSLT Processor runs

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

**How to get info about which XSL version XSLT Processor runs?**

I am evaluating Saxon Home Edition (HE10-SJ). Since this package seems to come with both XSL2.0 and XSL3.0 I am wondering how to get info about which XSL the XSLT Processor will run. I am fully aware that one sets the XSL version in the XSL file, but even if I add the XSL version in the XSL to 5 (that obviously doesn't exists), it will still run and process.

I also understand that if I would add code in XSL stylesheet that is exlusive to work with XSL2.0/XSL3.0, and set the XSL stylesheet to XSL1.0 I would most probably get either an error or the XSLT would not process the request.

I added the flag "-t" to get some information but only see java version, not XSLT/XSL version. Extraction of result is here:

```
Saxon-HE 10.5J from Saxonica
Java version 11.0.10
Using parser com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "XSLT processor" generally conforms to one specific version of the "XSLT specification". It's possible that a particular software product includes XSLT processors for multiple versions of the specification, but it's best to think of them as different processors even if they share code.

Given an XSLT processor and a stylesheet, the processor looks at the @version attribute and this affects how it behaves.

If @version="1.0", then an XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processor will evaluate some constructs in "backwards compatibility mode", which is closer to the way that an XSLT 1.0 processor would have handled them. But it remains an XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processor, following the rules of the 2.0 or 3.0 specification, and if the stylesheet uses constructs that require 2.0 or 3.0, these constructs will still work.

If version="5.0", say, the processor will work in "forwards compatibility mode", which basically means that it ignores constructs that it doesn't understand. The original intent of forwards compatibility mode was primarily for deployment on the web, to make it easier to write stylesheets that ran with any browser regardless which XSLT version it supported. It hasn't been very successful in achieving this aim, (a) because browsers have never moved beyond 1.0, and (b) because simply ignoring new constructs often leaves you with unusable results. This kind of concept makes much more sense for a language like CSS than it does for XSLT.

Answer (score 3):

Saxon 9.8 and later are XSLT 3 processors, of course you can run XSLT 2 code or even XSLT 1.0 code with them, XSLT 1.0 in backwards compatible mode https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#backwards.

You can check `system-property('xsl:version')` for the XSLT version and also a property `xsl:supports-backwards-compatibility` if the backwards compatibility mode is supported; it is in Saxon 10, 9.9 and later 9.8 releases. I think only the earliest 9.8 HE releases tried to disable that mode.

Comment: Seems Saxon 10 will judge which XSL version to run based on <?xml-stylesheet version="1.0"?>. Despite of which version I add in this mentioned code, the system-property('xsl:version') will alway printout "3.0", even if I intentionally add a fault error, e.g. 5.

Comment: `system-property()` will return the (highest) version the processor **supports**. It will always run that version, but if your stylesheet declares version 1.0, it will run in "compatibility mode": https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#backwards

Comment: Using `version="5.0"` is not an error, it puts the XSLT3 processor in forwards compatible mode. I don't know where you got the idea that the `xml-stylesheet` pi declares the XSLT version.

Comment: Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments, ask them separately as new questions with all the details of what you tried, which result or error you get, which result you expect.

Comment: And do start with the documentation https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/conformance/xslt30.html and https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/conformance/xslt20.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that seems to do the trick, but surely there has to be any easier way?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public final class StringSource extends StreamSource {

    final String string;

    private StringSource(final String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
    @Override
    public Reader getReader() {
        return new StringReader(string);
    }

    private static final String STYLESHEET = ""
            + "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"1.0\">"
            +     "<xsl:output method=\"xml\" omit-xml-declaration=\"yes\" />"
            +     "<xsl:template match=\"/\"><xsl:value-of select=\"system-property('xsl:version')\"/></xsl:template>"
            + "</xsl:stylesheet>";

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        final Templates    templates   = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTemplates(new StringSource(STYLESHEET));

        final StringWriter writer      = new StringWriter();

        final Transformer  transformer = templates.newTransformer();
        ;                  transformer.transform(new StringSource("<AnyOldXml/>"), new StreamResult(writer));

        System.out.println("Max. Supported XSLT Version.: " + writer);
    }
}
```